# Trying to display to a view from another class

Tags: java, android, android-layout, logcat

So when i try to display some text to a screen i get a error that i will post below. this text that will display is suppose to display a variable actually. It will display how many points the player has acquired. I took one way off the internet a long time ago. It compiles, but i get many LogCat errors. Here is the main class that i am trying to display the text with.

```
    public class Main extends Activity {
    DrawingView v;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        LinearLayout layout1 = new LinearLayout (this);
        FrameLayout game = new FrameLayout(this);
        DrawingView v = new DrawingView (this);

        TextView myText = new TextView(this);

        Button redCircle = new Button(this);



        redCircle.setWidth(300);
        redCircle.setText(DrawingView.addPoints);


        layout1.addView(myText);
        layout1.addView(redCircle); 
        redCircle.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        game.addView(myText);
        game.addView(v);
        game.addView(layout1);
        setContentView(v);
        //redCircle.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        // re-starts this activity from game-view. add this.finish(); to remove from stack
   }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



}
```

and here is the LogCat error i get. Please do not vote down this problem was described in very great detail with very few grammatical errors. I know all you internet trolls, and nazi's will do your best to do what you do best.

```
    04-20 01:51:42.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3154): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 01:51:42.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3154): Process: com.Tripps.thesimplegame, PID: 3154
04-20 01:51:42.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3154): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Tripps.thesimplegame/com.Tripps.thesimplegame.Main}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
04-20 01:51:42.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3154):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
04-20 01:51:42.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3154):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
04-20 01:51:42.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3154):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
04-20 01:51:42.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3154):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
04-20 01:51:42.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3154):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-20 01:51:42.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3154):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-20 01:51:42.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3154):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
04-20 01:51:42.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3154):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-20 01:51:42.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3154):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-20 01:51:42.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3154):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
04-20 01:51:42.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3154):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
04-20 01:51:42.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3154): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
04-20 01:51:42.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3154):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:274)
04-20 01:51:42.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3154):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4122)
04-20 01:51:42.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3154):     at com.Tripps.thesimplegame.Main.onCreate(Main.java:38)
04-20 01:51:42.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3154):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
04-20 01:51:42.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3154):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
04-20 01:51:42.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3154):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
04-20 01:51:42.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3154):     ... 10 more
```

here is another class might be very helpful or very confusing either way here you go

```
public DrawingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }
    RectF rectf = new RectF(0, 0, 200, 0);

    private static final int w = 100;
    public static int lastColor = Color.BLACK;
    private final Random random = new Random();
    private final Paint paint = new Paint();
    private final int radius = 230;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    public static int redColor = Color.RED;
    public static int greenColor = Color.GREEN;
    int randomWidth = 0;
    int randomHeight = 0;
    public static int addPoints = 0;

     //TextView myTextView = new TextView(this);



     //redCircle.setWidth(300);
     //redCircle.setText("Start Game");


    private final Runnable updateCircle = new Runnable() {
        @Override 
        public void run() {
            lastColor = random.nextInt(2) == 1 ? redColor : greenColor;
            paint.setColor(lastColor);
            invalidate();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

        }
    };

    @Override 
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        handler.post(updateCircle);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        handler.removeCallbacks(updateCircle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // your other stuff here
        if(random == null){
            randomWidth =(int) (random.nextInt(Math.abs(getWidth()-radius/2)) + radius/2f);
            randomHeight = (random.nextInt((int)Math.abs((getHeight()-radius/2 + radius/2f))));
        }else {
            randomWidth =(int) (random.nextInt(Math.abs(getWidth()-radius/2)) + radius/2f);
            randomHeight = (random.nextInt((int)Math.abs((getHeight()-radius/2 + radius/2f))));
        }

        canvas.drawCircle(randomWidth, randomHeight + radius/2f, radius, paint);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
   int x = (int) event.getX();
   int y = (int) event.getY();
   if(isInsideCircle(x, y) ==  true){
      //Do your things here
       if(redColor == lastColor){
          Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), YouFailed.class);
          v.getContext().startActivity(i);
       } else {
           addPoints++;
       }
   }else {

   }
   return true;
}

public boolean isInsideCircle(int x, int y){
  if ((((x - randomWidth)*(x - randomWidth)) + ((y - randomHeight)*(y - randomHeight))) < ((radius)*(radius)))
    return true;
  return false;    
}











}
```

Comment: Can you please clean your project?

Comment: @devin you add the views to "game" and then set the contentView to "v"?

Answer (score 2):

The error is in

```
int w = getResources().getInteger(Color.RED);
```

`getInteger()` expects a `res` value. `Color.RED` has value `0xffff0000` which is not found in res. Hence the error.

`Color.RED` is already an integer. Your resource values are also integers. Hence when it is trying to find a resource with value `Color.RED` or `0xffff0000`, it is giving error, because no such resource exists.

Looking from your code, it seems that you are not using XMLs to set your layout. So the way you are using

```
int w = getResources().getInteger(Color.RED);
Button redCircle = (Button) findViewById(w);
```

seems incorrect. Because your layout doesn't have any such object. You should just create a new button.

```
Button redCircle = new Button(context);
```

and add it to the layout.

Also,

```
redCircle.setText(DrawingView.addPoints);
```

`setText()` expects String or `char[]`. You should probably change that also if `addPoints` is not String. You can also pass some `res` value by using `R.string.some_string` which you should define in your res/values folder. Just for the demo, change it to `redCicle.setText("Red Circle");`

`DrawingView.addPoints` is also integer. So when you pass `redCircle.setText(DrawingView.addPoints);`, compiler assumes that you are passing some `res` value because they are mapped based on integers. Here, `addPoints` value seems to be 0 and hence, the compiler looks for a resource with map value `0` which is not found and hence it is throwing error `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0`.

TL;DR : `Resource` values are mapped based on integers. `setText()`, `findViewById()`, `getResources().getInteger()`, etc expect an integer which is mapped to that particular resource. If you pass some random integer (by mistake), it is going to look for that resource, because compilers are dumb (maybe. maybe not.), and will throw an exception when the resource is not found.

Comment: i kind of had that idea, but what would i replace that with?

Comment: i dont know what a "res" value is?

Comment: "res" are basically something that you keep in your resources. Your custom colors, layouts, drawables, etc. You android basics seem a little weak. You should quickly go through with the basics.

Comment: Button redCircle = new Button(this);

Answer (score 0):

```
canvas.drawText("Score: " + addPoints, 120, 300, paint);
```

This is the correct way to do it if anyone else has this problem!